# If I call an agent with runOnServer from an xPage application does it release control back to the xPage?

Tags: xpages, agents

I know calling agents from the web can have performance issues.  I don't want to block the end user while the agent is running. When you call an agent with runonserver does it block the xPage from continuing to process or will it run the agent independent of the xPage?

Comment: The most important is - can your agent (or whatever) run asynchronously? Does the page require outcome of that agent?

Comment: No it does not.  It is purely a back end process to update existing documents with the new registration id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does block. Use [a thread](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99U64Q) for non blocking operation. There is also an OpenNTF project for that.

Once you are there: why an agent? You pay a performance penalty. Better use the new OpenNTF Domino API

Comment: I bet you: rewriting and cleaning it up is the better approach. Only one (you the developer) suffers for a while, but the users (many) will benefit. And as we all know: the needs of the many ...

Comment: Actually the code I have is a web service I wrote that was consumed in a Flex application.  I re-wrote the flex application now in xPages but don't know how to call the web service from the xPages application .  They are both running on the same Domino server.  I thought I would tweak the web service to be a Java agent and call it if I could do it without the blocking.  Not sure I have the time to figure out the thread application.  It's a bit above my paygrade.

Comment: Read my blog entry on Web services: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SUKV5 and the tasks project on OpenNTF makes threads easy